# How to wait and get return value from ViewModel using Caliburn Micro ActivateItem

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro, nancy

I'm developing a desktop application that can communicate with a browser. What I  want is to send a parameter from the browser to the desktop app to do some process and then get the return value as value.

In the app, I use `Nancy` to get POST data from the browser. Then I pass the data to `SignHashViewModel` as parameter to do some process, but I can't get the value from `SignHashViewModel`.

I'm trying to learn `async` and `await` to see if that can solve the problem, but I don't know how to apply it to my code.

Javascript code below posts a string hash to the `Nancy` server and gets the result back:

**Signhash.php**

```
<?php

  if (isset($_GET['hashStr'])) 
  {
    $hashStr = $_GET['hashStr']; // get param from URL
  }
?>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        var hash = JSON.stringify("<?php echo $hashStr ?>");

        $.post("http://localhost:50011/MyProject/signHash", {hash}, function(data) //this line will post hash to nancy server and get the data as result
        {
            var result = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log("ErrCode : " + result.ErrCode );
            console.log("ErrMsg : " + result.ErrMsg );
            console.log("CertData : " + result.CertData );
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

to get POST data from the javascript i used this class.

**ServerModule.cs**

```
Post ("/signHash", (args) =>
{
  string result = null;
  List<string> dataItem= new List<string>();

  ActivateItems.OpenItem(new SignHashViewModel(dataItem)); //This line activate the screen with param

  return result; // Here I dont know how to get return value from SignHashViewModel
});
```

This class will sign a hash

**SignHashViewModel.cs**

```
public SignHashViewModel(List<string> dataItem)
{
   DataItem = dataItem; // Set as Property
}

public PDFInfo Sign() //Run this method when button is clicked
{
   PDFInfo pi = new PDFInfo();
   SignHashToken jsonData = new SignHashToken();

   pi = jsonData.SignHash(DataItem , userPin); //

   return result;
}
```

I expected that I could get the result of `SignHashViewModel` and pass to the browser. Hope someone could help me on this or providing any other solution would be great too, thank you.

Comment: It's unclear what you want to to "wait" for. Why don't you simply call `Sign()` before you return `result`?

Comment: The flow is like, when app receive a dataItem.. the `ActivateItems` will show  the SignHashView. From there, user need to enter pin then click `Sign()` button and get the result @mm8

Comment: Is that possible to `ActivateItems` and call `Sign()` at the same time?

Comment: Why don't you do whatever you want to do when the button is clicked in `Sign()`?

Comment: im successfully do what you have said, but in the `Sign()` need a `userPin` input from textbox in GUI . Somehow, i need to wait until user insert the pin and then proceed

Comment: Just bind the `TextBox` to a property of the view model?